# Search multiple subdocuments in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given the following collection:

```
{
    name: User1
    tags: [
        {k:"group", v:"test"},
        {k:"color", v:"blue"}
    ]
},
{
    name: User2
    tags: [
        {k:"group", v:"dev"},
        {k:"color", v:"blue"}
    ]
},
{
    name: User3
    tags: [
        {k:"group", v:"dev"},
        {k:"color", v:"red"}
    ]
}
```

How would I go about searching the `"tags"` field to find a given user.

For example for `User2`, I can search for one tag at a time with match:

```
db.users.find({tags: {$elemMatch: {k:"group", v:"dev"}}})
```

Which results in: `User2 and User3`. Or

```
db.users.find({tags: {$elemMatch: {k:"color", v:"blue"}}})
```

Which results in: `User1 and User2`

But when I try to do

```
db.users.find({tags: {$elemMatch: {$and: [{k:"group", v:"dev"}, {k:"color", v:"blue"}]})
```

I get no matches.

How can I search for `User2` record?

Comment: Take a look at unwind: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: try $or instead of and

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSayed Using $or results in me getting all three records

Comment: values for `k and v` are strings right?

Comment: @Shrabanee correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the results that I wanted by using the $all operator with $elemMatch

```
db.task.find({tags: {$all: [
    {$elemMatch: {k:"group", v:"dev"}}, 
    {$elemMatch: {k:"color", v:"blue"}}
  ]}})
```

See [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#use-all-with-elemmatch) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Aggregate()`, for your problem.

Try this query :-

```
db.users.aggregate([
   {$project: {'name': 1}}, 
   {$unwind: '$tags'},
   {$match: {'k':     'group', 'v': 'dev'}}
 ])
```

[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/emphasized text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/emphasized%20text)

Comment: This query doesn't return any results

Answer (score -1):

Try this query:

```
db.temp4.find({$and:[{"tags":{"k":"group","v":"dev"}},{"tags":{"k":"color","v":"blue"}}]})
```

It returns the required result